# Bootstrap 5 column text overlapping

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have created a basic webpage using Bootstrap 5 and I have noticed that the column text is overlapping. The code is below and the image is attached. At full screen the text is fine and the text reduces in size as I continue to lower the screen size until the columns kick in and it fixes.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-5">

        <h1 class="display-1">Welcome to this site</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 col-md-7">

        <h1 class="display-1">Welcome to this site</h1>

    </div>


</div>
```

[image: screenprint]

Any ideas as none of the suggestions I have seen so far seem to work for me.

I have tried different column sizes and expected the text to reduce before overlapping.

Comment: Please post a minimal working example so we can see what's going on. I copied your divs into a bootstrap template and they display fine.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue with your code example and Bootstrap v5.2. Please provide a minimal example that can reproduce the problem/issue you're facing.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution that maybe will help you! We need to add the "text-break" class in the h1 tag.

Thanks! :)

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-4 col-md-5">

    <h1 class="text-break display-1">Welcome to this site</h1>

</div>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-8 col-md-7">

    <h1 class="text-break display-1">Welcome to this site</h1>

</div>
```